# Can't export csv table with decimal: "," in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have superset running in the docker. After I change superset_config. py added this (and "restart app"):
`CSV_EXPORT = {"encoding": "cp1251", "sep": ";", "decimal": ","}`
The encoding and seps are right, but float numbers are still have default decimal equal to ".".

As I suggest superset does not correct recognise datatype in datasets while export it in CSV, because d3 formatting and conditional formatting work correctly (except comparison records which having zero value, maybe its the same problem), but there are two different implementations: one using python + pandas and another using js/ts.

For example consider this small dataset produced by this query (using Oracle dB):

`SELECT 1.1 AS "1", 1 AS "2" FROM DUAL`

In the dataset edit menu:

[image: Снимок экрана (2)]

There, we see to only `INT` type.

If I try to export it in CSV, the file look that:

1;2
1.1;1

I did not find information about "Superset dataset types". As I assume "Superset dataset types" equivalent to Python data types. I saw `int` and `string` column types. Is there a way to cast/change the column type to float, or my guesses are incorrect?

The best option is the export .csv with d3 formatting applied on the table (it seems like I did it once, but can't reproduce it another time). This feature is good for opening .csv with Excel, without "import".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I can help you improve the translation of your text from Russian to English. Here's the corrected version:

It seems that there is indeed a bug in the code. The file "superset/superset/utils/csv.py" handles escape characters, which is causing the problem. The corresponding branches on Github are somewhat confusing, but if you need a fix right now, it's worth carefully examining this file and making the necessary adjustments. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the temporary solutions I used, at least not as an example.

As far as I can tell, the problem is localized to the "df_to_escaped_csv" function, which is called by an HTTP request when the user imports tables as a .csv file.

From what I remember and understand, the issue is that this function does not recognize fractional numbers in the dataframe as numbers, since they are presented as strings (or are converted to such).

In other words, when returning the value of "df.to_csv(**kwargs)", the "DECIMAL" parameter is not applied to the values of these fields, since they are not floats but rather strings.